# how to deploy war file in tomcat using bitbucket pipeline

Tags: tomcat, sftp, war, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

How to deploy war file in tomcat using Bitbucket Pipeline using Tomcat user?

How can i use **SFTP** using ssh-key?

```
`git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD  "sftp://35.150.122.100/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SFTP Deploy pipe from Bitbucket team](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/sftp-deploy/src/master/).

Add this code to your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`:

```
- pipe: atlassian/sftp-deploy:0.5.3
  variables:
    USER: '<string>'
    SERVER: '<string>'
    REMOTE_PATH: '<string>'
    LOCAL_PATH: '<string>' # Optional.
    # SSH_KEY: '<string>' # Optional.
    # PASSWORD: '<string>' # Optional.
    # EXTRA_ARGS: '<string>' # Optional.
    # DEBUG: '<boolean>' # Optional.
```

Also you have to update the known hosts in your Bitbucket repository.Check the [official guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html?_ga=2.40924257.2134500036.1580201282-116330337.1579082280#UseSSHkeysinBitbucketPipelines-Step2:Updatetheknownhosts).